# Meaning of the word 'quedaban'

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Can anyone explain the meaning of this sentence in English:

"Pero recordó su pobre hogar y los seres tan hambrientos y desnudos que quedaban en él."

What does "quedaban" mean here?

Comment: I can't give a proper answer, but I believe what you should be looking for is the meaning of "quedar *en*", as this is separate from "quedar". Plus there are some regional variations, so knowing the source of the sentence would be helpful.

Comment: I would translate _quedaban en el_ as _lived there_

Comment: It does **not** mean *stayed* (quedar**se**), but *remained*. "He remembered his meager home and the ever so hungry and defenseless souls that *remained* [were left] there." --- ex. *Solo algunas personas quedaron del grupo original* = Only some people from the original group were left/remained [from the whole].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But he remembered his poor home, and the so hungry and naked beings that *still were there*.

I think there's not a direct literal for this. **Quedaban** in this sentence means that there were more beings before, but there are some that are not there anymore and there are only some remaining. So you can translate this to:

- Still lived there
- Remained there
- Were left

Comment: Isn't "remain," as you've suggested, exactly a direct, literal translation of "quedar"?  It might not be the most natural choice if you were saying this in English, but it's not wrong either.

Comment: Depending on the case, in this setting maybe it is

Answer (score 0):

i read that like remaining, just like this example

Sentence in english:

"After finishing the assignment, I used the **remaining** time to study."

Traducing that to spanish:

"Después de terminar la tarea, usé el tiempo **restante** para estudiar."

What could be like:

"Después de terminar la tarea, usé el tiempo **que me quedaba** para estudiar"

Using your example:

"Pero recordó su pobre hogar y los seres tan hambrientos y desnudos **que quedaban** en él."

With remaining
Spanish:
"Pero recordó su pobre hogar y los seres tan hambrientos y desnudos **restantes** en él."

English:
"But he remembered his poor home and the hungry and naked beings **remaining** in it."

Thats it, im hope that you are well.